# error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

Tags: c++, linux, function, pointers

I am trying to pass error to main function using pass by reference, but when I compile the below code I get an error as

**error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)**

**Main code :**

```
main()
{
.
.
int error=-1;
foo(..., error);
.
.
}
```

**Function Code:**

```
foo(..., int &error)
{
    if ( ...)
        *error = errno;
}
```

errno is the standard error set from system call in linux.

The  header file defines the integer variable errno, which is set by system calls and some library functions in the event of an error to indicate what went wrong.

Comment: References are not pointers. Unary `*` is for pointers. `error` is a reference.

Comment: your foo function takes a reference and you treat it as a pointer

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`error` is not pointer, you can't use indirection (dereference) operator `operator*` on it.

If you just want set its value, change

```
*error = errno;
```

to

```
error = errno;
```

Comment: I saw an example somewhere like this..

void foo(int &value)
{
    *value = 6;
}
 
int main()
{
    int value = 5;
 
    cout << "value = " << value << '\n';
    foo(value);
    cout << "value = " << value << '\n';
    return 0;
}

Will this also have same problem?

Comment: @mooli Definitly yes.

Answer (score 2):

In your foo function you use a reference, later you use it as a pointer.
references are not pointers so your compiler throws you an error. Change the function to accept a pointer instead.

Comment: Did it fix your problem ?

Comment: Yes, it did fix the problem. Thank you