# error invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int') with modules

Tags: c++, pointers, module

i try to use a vector whit a pointer and modules.
I have this problem with c++:
In main.cpp:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #include "Funcion1.hpp"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int vec[20];
    int *punteroV = &vec[0];
    for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese numero: ";
        cin>>vec[i];
    }
    cout<<FUN(*punteroV) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and in the module:

```
#include "Funcion1.hpp"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int FUN(int &punteroV){

    int num;
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<10;j++){
            cout<<"i: "<<(punteroV+ i)<<endl<<"j: "<<(punteroV + j)<<endl;
            if(*(punteroV + i) > *(punteroV + j)){
                num = (punteroV + i);
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

and in the module .hpp

```
   #ifndef FUNCION1_H
#define FUNCION1_H
int FUN(int&);
#endif
```

Compiler produces an error:

```
  error invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
```

What this error means?

Comment: It means that `punterOv+i` is an `int`, and not a pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: invalid type argument of unary ‘\*’ (have ‘int’)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521200/error-invalid-type-argument-of-unary-have-int)

Comment: Is a pointer in int `*punteroV = &vec[0];`

Comment: @SantiagoSantosisma That's a different `punterOv` variable, and that's not the line the error message is pointing to.

Comment: Your pointer in `main()` has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with a ***reference*** to an `int` called `punterOv` in `FUN`(), so `punterOv+i`, in `FUN`(), is an `int`. Review the chapter in your C++ book that explains what references are, and how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function FUN you have this line:

```
   if(*(punteroV + i) > *(punteroV + j))
```

You are trying to do pointer arithmetic on a reference to an integer, and then deference it like an `int*`  You cannot do that directly on the reference. To do math on the reference you must first take its address like this:

```
   if(*(&punteroV + i) > *(&punteroV + j)){
```